# php: how to get name from object

Tags: php, arrays, object

this might be very simple, and well, yes ... I may not fully understand how objects work, which seems to be the real problem here. So thanks for helping! ^^

I've got an Object that kinda looks like this.

```
$myobject = Array( [some_random_name] => "Value to that random name" )
```

Since I'm not sure how those two bits of information are called (sry for that) I will refer to them as "name" and "value". My question is: how do I extract these informations? I need both, the "name" and the "value", so I can store them in two variables (`$namevar`, `$nameval`), which should then output something like this:

```
echo($namevar) = "some_random_name"

echo($nameval) = "Value to that random name"
```

Thanks.

Comment: like `array_keys` and `array_values` in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you are using an Array, not an object. in order to get the array keys or values, you could use the following functions: array_values & array_keys.

i could add code snippets etc, but its really straight forward in php's docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

you could also possibly iterate the array or object (works the same for both), using something like the following code:

`foreach($object as $key => $value) { ... }`

Comment: Damn, I thought I had tried that one in the runup to my posting, but I guess I didnt :-S ... anyway, it did the trick, so thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking how do we get the value of array objects? how do we use them?

These are array objects.

echo $yourObjectname->yourpropertyname;

in your case

echo $myobject->some_random_name;

**Example -**

```
$arr = Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => 'abc'

    );
echo $arr[0]->name;
```

Object is an instance of class or we can say an medium to use classes properties variable and methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$myobject = [ 'key' => 'value' ]; 

$key = key($myobject);
$value = $myobject[$key];

echo $key; // key
echo $value; // value
```

it will return the key value for the current array element

[see documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

or you can use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach($myobject as $key => $value) {
    $namevar = $key;
    $nameval = $value;
}
```